# How do I change the default password of MySQL root user on Cloudbees?

Tags: mysql, cloudbees

We are running Jenkins on Cloudbees for building our code base from Github repo for MifosX. For our Integration Test job, we need to create a MySQL DB before each run. We have been able to do that, but would like to change the default MySQL credentials which are "root" and blank password, to some specific "password". Can someone guide us on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are following [this guide](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/MySQL).

If that's the case, you should be able to follow standard MySQL instructions for setting the root users' password:

```
mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
```

But I'm not sure why you would want to secure this with a password. Any network ports are isolated from other users, and they certainly don't have access to your files.

Comment: Our integration test scripts expect the MySQL DB to have a username/password. I guess, as a good habit, even in "training" we would like to follow the "rules" : )